# Performance of different devices on Android AVD

Tags: android, benchmarking, android-virtual-device

I have been trying to calculate the overhead of device emulation using android AVD. As benchmark, I have been using Roy longbottom's android benchmarks (whetstone, both java and native).
http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/android%20benchmarks.htm

The results (MFLOPS) of all emulated devices (Nexus one to Nexus 5) are pretty much in same range (120-150 MFLOPS). However, the underlying hardware profiles of the devices are very different in CPU frequency. I have also tried to increase/decrease the RAM of the AVD, but still results do not vary much. Does that mean that AVD does not emulate actual device profile?
This fact can be also shown from CPU MHz benchmark which shows 0 MHz for the device (the benchmark does not get the CPU frequency form /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state )
Kindly elaborate on this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

In my program, CPU MHz is obtained from /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq. This does not appear to be available via Eclipse and BlueStacks emulators, where zero MHz is also produced. For a true representation, the emulator would need to take into account power saving options and battery charge.

In developing those benchmarks, via Eclipse, I used various general purpose phone and tablet Android Virtual Devices, mainly for different screen sizes. As far as I can remember, they all produced the same execution speeds, subject to having the appropriate hardware feature. There were no options to select CPU speed, but I didn’t expect one.